# How to convert GeoJSON to GeoTIFF

Tags: qgis, python, geojson, geotiff-tiff, java

I'm looking for a way to convert a GeoJSON file to a GeoTIFF (georeferenced image) in Python or Java.

The inverse is possible using [rasterio](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the command line, https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_rasterize.html

With Python, you can use `gdal.RasterizeLayer` like in the tests from GDAL e.g https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/autotest/alg/rasterize.py

With Java, you can use the same function from Java bindings https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/gdal/swig/java/javadoc.java#L733 (PS: considering you made a build to support Java or installed an existing GDAL with Java support)

You can also use [`gdal.Rasterize`](https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal-module.html#Rasterize). It takes the same input arguments as the command line contrary to `gdal.RasterizeLayer`.